# Select for one gender, age group and marital status using groupby() and display a frequency distribution using value_counts()

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

## Groupby Help Needed

I would like to output a frequency table showing marital status ("DMDMARTLx") for women ("RIAGENDR" ==2) in all age groups. The code below returns the age group stratification and counts the marital status correctly but I am struggling to understand why I can't select just the women from the the dataframe.

```
da["agegrp"] = pd.cut(da.RIDAGEYR, [18, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80])
da["RIAGENDRf"] = da["RIAGENDR"] == 2
da.groupby(['agegrp', 'RIAGENDRf']) ['DMDMARTLx'].value_counts()

agegrp    RIAGENDRf  DMDMARTLx       
(18, 30]  False      Never Married       262
                     Married             104
                     Living w Partner     95
                     Separated             7
                     Divorced              2
                     Widowed               2
          True       Never Married       259
                     Married             158
                     Living w Partner    114
                     Divorced             11
                     Separated            11
...
```

If I use the [] to select the data within da["RIAGENDR"] == 2, I get a value error:

```
da["agegrp"] = pd.cut(da.RIDAGEYR, [18, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80])
da["RIAGENDRf"] = [da["RIAGENDR"]==2]
da.groupby(['agegrp', 'RIAGENDRf']) ['DMDMARTLx'].value_counts()

ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

Does this mean I need to fill or drop missing data?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a dataframe for women then you must write :

```
da_women = da[da["RIAGENDR"] == 2]
```